# Como tratar erros no create do sequelize

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, node.js, sequelize-js

Ola, gostaria de saber de qual maneira posso tratar possiveis erros ao realizar um create com sequelize por exemplo considerando a seguinte inserção

```
 Livros.create({
            BK_TITLE: data.title,
            BK_GENRE: data.genre,
            BK_AUTOR: data.author,
            BK_OBS: data.obs
        })
```

Tem alguma forma de identificar se ele inseriu com sucesso ou apresentou erro por exemplo a falta de um input ou algo do tipo para que eu possa tratar no meu front-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso seria alterar o create para ficar desta forma:

```js
Livros.create({
 BK_TITLE: data.title,
 BK_GENRE: data.genre,
 BK_AUTOR: data.author,
 BK_OBS: data.obs
}).then(function(item){
 console.log(item); //Item gravado
}).catch(function (err) {
 console.log(err); //Erro ao gravar
});
```